# CRTP why is member lookup runtime?

Tags: c++11, crtp

Or at least I think it is.
Consider the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct BaseBase {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual ~BaseBase(){}
};

template <typename Derived>
struct Base : BaseBase{
    void foo() override{
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo();
    }
};

struct D1 : Base<D1> {};
struct Unrelated {};

// no runtime polymorphism
template <typename SDerived>
struct SBase{
    void foo() {
        static_cast<SDerived*>(this)->foo();
    }
};

struct SD1 : SBase<SD1> {};


template <typename T, typename ...Args>
void doFoo(Args&&... args){
    T* t = new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    t->foo();
}

int main(){
    doFoo<Unrelated>(); //compile time error, foo not found in unrelated
    doFoo<SD1>(); //runtime crash
    doFoo<D1>(); //runtime crash
    return 0;
}
```

I was hoping the compiler would be nice enough to check for the existence of `foo`at compile time in `doFoo` but in both cases, with `virtual` in base, and without `virtual` in base the code compiles just fine but crashes at runtime.

Why is this?

Edit: clang setup

```
clang version 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

with `doFoo<Unrelated>()` commented out  compiles.

and g++ setup

```
gcc version 7.1.1 20170630 (GCC)
```

compiles with `doFoo<Unrelated>()` commented out.

Comment: In its current state, I don't think this code should compile. There's an obvious problem with the definition of `SD1`. CRTP class `SBase` is trying to call the `foo` member function of `SDerived`. But when it is instantiated with `SD1` as the template parameter, this member function doesn't exist. So this program is ill-formed. I don't think that gcc or clang would compile this program without errors. Can you confirm that this is indeed the code that compiles and produces a runtime crash?

Comment: @ChrisBeck When `SBase<SD1>::foo()` is called, it does indeed try to call `foo` on the `SDerived*` pointer.  In this case, `SDerived` is `SD1`.  And `SD1` does have a `foo` member that can be called.  It happens to be the inherited member `SBase<SD1>::foo`.

Comment: @aschepler: Thanks, that's pretty unfortunate for the author of the code

Comment: @ChrisBeck Yes but I am having a good laugh at it.

Comment: If you would use a debugger, in less than 20 seconds, you could know the problem with your code.  It would have take 5 time less time to do that that writing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because both of the classes have a function called foo. It's present in the base class for each class.

However, all that function does is call itself, which will eventually result in a stack overflow.

Comment: How did I miss this, the compiler sees a foo in both classes because it is visible in the parent struct... dont code at 2 in the morning: )